# Join Three Multiple Table with Difference Column

Tags: sql, vb.net

currently for table `LEDGER` and `NUSER` is okay.. but i need to join another table which is `LEDGER_HISTORY`. for `LEDGER_HISTORY` i just want field name `STATUS` only.. can anyone help me to solve it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LED.IDX AS IDX,
                CORPCODE,
                UNITTYPECODE,
                UPPERFORMATIONCODE,
                FORMATIONCODE,
                LED.UNITCODE AS UNITCODE,
                LED.STORECODE AS STORECODE,
                LED.SECTIONNO AS SECTIONNO,
                LED.PARTNO AS PARTNO,
                LED.BATCHNO AS BATCHNO,
                UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE,
                LEDGERDATE,
                ENTITLEMENT,
                HOLDING,
                SURPLUS,
                SHORTAGE,
                COSTHOLDING,
                COSTENTITLEMENT,
                INITIALSTOCK,
                EMPLOYQTY,
                FIGHTQTY,
                ITEMAGE1,
                ITEMAGE2,
                ITEMAGE3,
                ITEMAGE4,
                LED.BAH_BEREK,
                LED.JENIS_BEREK,
                JPTD_NO,
                LASTUPDATE,
                LED.ITEMTYPECODE AS ITEMTYPECODE,
                LED.TOOLTYPECODE AS TOOLTYPECODE,
                LED.PAKAIBHGCODE,
                LED.PAKAICODE,
                ITEMNIDX,
                LED.CREATEID AS CREATEID,
                LED.UPDATEID AS UPDATEID,
                LED.CREATEDATE AS CREATEDATE,
                LED.UPDATEDATE AS UPDATEDATE,
                USERID,
                RANKCODE,
                SERVICENO,
                USERNAME,
                DESIGNATIONCODE,
                PASSWORD,
                'OPER' AS GROUPCODE,
                5 AS ACESSID
FROM (LEDGER AS LED) "
LEFT JOIN NUSER ON NUSER.USERID = LED.UPDATEID
WHERE (1=1)
UNION
SELECT STATUS
FROM LEDGER_HISTORY
WHERE STATUS='1'
```

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly share your schema, sample Data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

Simply add **1 as status** to your select statement instead of joining or doing union to other table

```
        Select DISTINCT LED.IDX As IDX, CORPCODE, UNITTYPECODE, UPPERFORMATIONCODE, FORMATIONCODE, LED.UNITCODE As UNITCODE,LED.STORECODE As STORECODE, LED.SECTIONNO As SECTIONNO, LED.PARTNO As PARTNO, LED.BATCHNO As BATCHNO, UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE, LEDGERDATE, ENTITLEMENT, HOLDING, SURPLUS, SHORTAGE, COSTHOLDING, COSTENTITLEMENT, INITIALSTOCK, EMPLOYQTY, FIGHTQTY, ITEMAGE1, ITEMAGE2, ITEMAGE3, ITEMAGE4, LED.BAH_BEREK, LED.JENIS_BEREK, JPTD_NO, LASTUPDATE, LED.ITEMTYPECODE As ITEMTYPECODE, LED.TOOLTYPECODE As TOOLTYPECODE, LED.PAKAIBHGCODE, LED.PAKAICODE, ITEMNIDX, LED.CREATEID As CREATEID, LED.UPDATEID As UPDATEID, LED.CREATEDATE As CREATEDATE, LED.UPDATEDATE As UPDATEDATE,USERID,RANKCODE, SERVICENO, USERNAME, DESIGNATIONCODE, PASSWORD ,'OPER' AS GROUPCODE,5 AS ACESSID
,1 as 'Status' FROM LEDGER AS LED  LEFT JOIN NUSER ON NUSER.USERID = LED.UPDATEID WHERE (1=1)
```

Comment: actually, in table ledger_history have same fieldname with table ledger.. but i just add a new field name which is STATUS.. the reason is, if user delete data in table LEDGER, the STATUS in LEDGER_HISTORY will be 1..

Comment: so  i want to combine all these 3 table, but for ledger_history, i just need value on status only